# C++ unordered_set's count and find don't work if it uses a custom class type as the key

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set

I'm having some issues using unordered_set with my specialized hash function.
I can insert elements without an issue, but when I try to find other elements using find or count it doesn't work. it can't find the elements that are already in the set.

Here's my hash function:

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v)
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

namespace std {
template<> 
    struct hash<Node>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const Node &node) const
        {
            size_t seed = 0;
            hash_combine(seed, node.getX());
            hash_combine(seed, node.getY());
            return seed;
        }
    };
}
```

My Node class have bunch of other member variables but I'm only combining X and Y. This should be enough since I can safely assume there cannot be 2 Nodes with same X and Y values. This is the fist time I'm getting my hands dirty with template specialization, am I doing something wrong? I think I might not be hashing them correctly.

Here's an example to further clarify my issue:

Let say I have a set called **mySet** that contains 4 Nodes(X Y) : **<1 7> <2 7> <3 7> <1 8>**

```
bool find1(Node *node)
{   
    unordered_set<Node*>::const_iterator it = mySet.find(node);
    return (it != mySet.end()); //will be false
}

bool find2(Node *node)
{
    return !mySet.count(node); //will be 1 (!0)
}
```

cout << find1(new Node(1,7)) << endl; // returns 0

cout << find2(new Node(1,7)) << endl; // returns 1

Anyone have any idea why element lookups don't work?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use pointers to the `Node`s: each `Node` has a different address with a different hash. The pointer value is used as key, not the `Node` pointed to.

Comment: Your `unordered_set<Node*>::const_iterator` suggests the element type is `Node*` not `Node`, so the hash specialisation is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `unordered_set` contains `Node*` and not `Node`, the pointers are being searched for and not the objects themselves. I don't know why `find2` would return 1, unless by coincidence you have 2 objects allocated to the same place.

If you tried to use a hashing function that took a `Node*` it wouldn't work either, because `unordered_set` also requires a working `==` operator to compare elements.

Comment: Hey, so sorry I just realized I forgot to accept your answer. Thank you for your answer, can't believe I failed to see that mistake.